# how to set log level for particular android application in eclipse

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-debug

My problem is that I could not find any output in logcat for csipsimple. Because of it, I am trapped of debugging. So could somebody tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What is "csipsimple"? What is your question? Show code you are using.

Comment: means I have a project. and i am not getting any output of **LOG** in logcat. And after some search the project member said **I've wrapped android util.Log inside my own wrapper. The log level of the application can be configured , using Settings -> User interface -> Log level. (where Settings is Settings of CSipSimple).** . And i dont know what he mean by that . I just understand that I have to increase the log level of the project. So please help me coz i am new in android.